# trying to find out which is unpack and format is faster results in sporadic behavior, why?

Tags: python, time, unpack, bitstring

I'm trying to accurately determine which method of unpacking binary data into a view-able format is faster. I'm attempting to use the time module to do so. I'm working with the bitstring module as I found this the easiest way when unpacking i'm working with bit aligned data. This is a small test case to see which way is faster as i'm processing millions of lines. It needs to be displayed in a specific way which is why the formatting is there.

```
from bitstring import BitArray
import time

s = BitArray('0x0081')
start = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    test = s.unpack('uintle:16')
    temp = hex(test[0]).lstrip('0x').zfill(4)
end = time.time()
ttime = end-start
print("uintle " + str(ttime))

start = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    hex_val = s.unpack('hex:16')
    temp = hex_val[0][2:]+hex_val[0][0:2]
end = time.time()
ttime = end-start
print("hex " + str(ttime))
```

when testing the condition on 1 million loops this is the output:

```
uintle 32.51800322532654
uintle 46.38693380355835
hex 131.79687571525574
```

It doesn't seem valid as it prints one output twice and I can't figure out why that happens. 
When testing with 100,000 loops this is the output:

```
uintle 2.705230951309204
hex 6.699380159378052
```

only two outputs just as expected. Any ideas on why it is behaving as such?

Comment: BTW, you should use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to measure execution times. I can't test your code because I don't have the `bitstring` module, but I agree that it's strange that you're getting the `uintle` stuff printed twice.

Comment: Changed the script to use timeit module:


`import timeit

setup = """
from bitstring import BitArray


def foo(s):
    hex_val = s.unpack('hex:16')
    temp = hex_val[0][2:]+hex_val[0][0:2]
    
def foo2(s):
    test = s.unpack('uintle:16')
    temp = hex(test[0]).lstrip('0x').zfill(4)
"""

t = timeit.Timer("foo(BitArray('0x0081'))", setup=setup)
print("unpack hex")
print(t.timeit(1000000))
t = timeit.Timer("foo2(BitArray('0x0081'))", setup=setup)
print("unpack uintle")
print(t.timeit(1000000))`

Comments don't take well to code apparently